# Handlebars with Assemble build returning "not an own property of its parent"

Tags: express, handlebars.js, assemble

I am experiencing the dreaded `not an "own property" of its parent` issue when attempting to build my Handlebars project.

I have been down the rabbit hole and seen the many explanations of using `@handlebars/allow-prototype-access` to allow the issue to be bypassed, however it seems the project does not use a standard implementation of Handlebars...

It seems I am using something called [`engine-handlebars`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/engine-handlebars)

Where I would expect to implement that `allow-prototype-access` change, I see the following:

```
app.pages('./source/pages/**/*.hbs');
app.engine('hbi', require('engine-handlebars'));
```

I can't fathom how I am supposed to implement the prototype access with this setup...

It seems, after a bit of trial and error, commenting lines out as I go, that the line `app.pages('./source/pages/**/*.hbs');` is actually causing the issue...

When I run the project with this line in, I get the error:

```
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "path" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
[10:54:49] ERROR - undefined: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined
```

Comment: What version of `engine-handlebars` are you using? Looks like in v1.0.0, it accepts the Handlebars instance as an argument. If so, you'd `allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars)` before passing that in.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [@handlebars/allow-prototype-access](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@handlebars/allow-prototype-access) works by modifying the `Handlebars` *instance*.

```
const _Handlebars = require('handlebars');
const { allowInsecurePrototypeAccess } = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access');

const Handlebars = allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(_Handlebars);
```

> Note that `allowInsecurePrototypeAccess` does not modify the instance in place, but creates an [isolated instance](https://github.com/handlebars-lang/allow-prototype-access/blob/a6975a8e6220800ba64e5059811672815355eda8/src/index.js#L2) via [`Handlebars.create()`](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime.html#handlebars-create) so you must use its return value.

In your case, [engine-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/engine-handlebars) exposes the `Handlebars` instance in different ways depending on what version you are using.

Based on your code you provided, my guess is you are using `<1.0.0`, but I'll provide methods for adjusting this for all its versions.

### engine-handlebars@<0.6.0

Unfortunately these versions don't expose `Handlebars` in any way, so if you are using this version I recommend upgrading engine-handlebars to a later version.

### engine-handlebars@>=0.6.0 <1.0.0

[Version 0.6.0 exposed](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/engine-handlebars/releases/tag/0.6.0) `Handlebars` as a [property](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/engine-handlebars/blob/0.6.0/index.js#L26) on the exported engine function. This is then referenced throughout the library via `this.Handlebars`.

You can then change this before setting the `app.engine()` and it should work.

```js
const _Handlebars = require('handlebars');
const { allowInsecurePrototypeAccess } = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access');
const engine = require('engine-handlebars');

// elsewhere...
// const app = ...

// Do this *before* setting app.engine
const insecureHandlebars = allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(_Handlebars);
engine.Handlebars = insecureHandlebars;

app.engine('hbi', engine);
```

### engine-handlebars@>=1.0.0

For [version 1.0.0](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/engine-handlebars/#v100) and beyond, you must pass the `Handlebars` instance yourself.

```js
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
const engine = require('engine-handlebars')(Handlebars);
```

Thus you don't need to set anything on `engine`, you just pass in the modified instance when you need it.

```js
const _Handlebars = require('handlebars');
const { allowInsecurePrototypeAccess } = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access');

// elsewhere...
// const app = ...

// Do this *before* setting app.engine
const insecureHandlebars = allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(_Handlebars);
const engine = require('engine-handlebars')(insecureHandlebars);

app.engine('hbi', engine);
```